# separate output into multiple objects in R automatically

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, automation, splice

I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way in R to run a command and have it save the output into multiple objects based on group? For instance, I wrote a code that calculates what number of employees are in a supervisory role based on their department.

```
library(tidyverse)
sample <- tibble(department = c("Admin", "Admin", "Office of President", "Office of President"),
                 sup_status = c("Not Supervisor", "Supervisor", "Not Supervisor", "Supervisor"),
                 n = c(918, 152, 69, 192))
```

But, what I really want is a vector of the percentages of supervisors by department. I can get R to produce one long vector of all percentages:

```
library(tidyverse)

vector_of_all_percents <- sample %>%
  group_by(department) %>%
  mutate(sum_new = sum(n)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum_new) %>%
  select(percent) %>%
  as_vector()

vector_of_all_percents
 percent1  percent2  percent3  percent4 
0.8579439 0.1420561 0.2643678 0.7356322
```

My actual data has many departments. Is there a way to adjust my above code to get R produce objects by department automatically, something like this:

```
vector_for_admin
 percent1  percent2
0.8579439 0.1420561 

vector_for_office
percent1  percent2 
0.2643678 0.7356322
```

I'm not sure if the slice() or split() commands are what I need, or if this is even possible. Any guidance would be very appreciated!

Comment: You can quite easily separate the output into different elements on a list. Would that be useful for you?

Comment: @iod, I'm not sure; I'm pretty sure I need a vector. My end goal with this output is to put it  into the prob argument of the sample() function  (i.e., department == "Administrative" ~ sample(c("Supervisor", "Not Supervisor"), 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(vector_for_admin))), and I think that I need a vector for that.

Comment: You just access the element of the list you need using the `$` operator. In my example below you would do `sample(c("Supervisor", "Not Supervisor"), 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(list_of_all_percents$Admin$percent)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` to create a list:

```r
library(tidyverse)
sample <- tibble(department =c("Admin", "Admin", "Office of President", "Office of President"),
                 sup_status =c("Not Supervisor", "Supervisor", "Not Supervisor", "Supervisor"),
                 n = c(918, 152, 69, 192))

list_of_all_percents <- sample %>%
  group_by(department) %>%
  mutate(sum_new = sum(n)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum_new) %>%
  split(.$department)

list_of_all_percents
#> $Admin
#> Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   department sup_status         n sum_new percent
#>   <chr>      <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Admin      Not Supervisor   918    1070   0.858
#> 2 Admin      Supervisor       152    1070   0.142
#> 
#> $`Office of President`
#> Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   department          sup_status         n sum_new percent
#>   <chr>               <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Office of President Not Supervisor    69     261   0.264
#> 2 Office of President Supervisor       192     261   0.736
```

So if you want to access percents for Admin, you just do

```
list_of_all_percents$Admin$percent
#> [1] 0.8579439 0.1420561
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of calling the elements from the list--I appreciate you also showing how it would fit in my call to sample()